Approximating a finite sum with an integral
Consider the following sum (with $a$ being a real number and $N$ an even integer)
$$S(a, N) = \sum_{m=1}^{N/2} \frac{4}{N+1} \sin^2\left( \frac{2\pi m}{N+1} \right)\sin \left( 2 a \cos \left( \frac{2\pi m}{N+1} \right) \right) $$
How to get approximate evaluation of this sum when $N \gg 1$?
I tried to turn $S(a, N)$ into the integral $I(a, N)$, but the integral is zero due to symmetry about $x=\pi/2$
$$I(a, N) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2}{\pi} \sin^2 \left(x \right) \sin \left( 2 a \cos \left( x \right) \right) \mathrm{d}x = 0 $$
So, how to find an approximate expression for $S(a, N)$ when $N$ is very large?

Combine symmetric terms (for $m$ and $N/2+1-m$)

@FedorPetrov Sorry, I should have said that $N$ is even so that $N/2$ is an integer. How to proceed is this case?

That's what I guessed. Still pair symmetric terms. They do not cancel completely.

First, we rewrite the sum as a sum over the full period
$$
S(a,N)=\frac{2}{N+1}\sum_{j=1}^{N+1}  \sin^2\left( \frac{2\pi j}{N+1} \right)\sin \left( 2 a \cos \left( \frac{2\pi j}{N+1} \right) \right).
$$
Denote
$$
g(k,m)=\sum _{j=1}^m \cos ^{k}\left(\frac{2 \pi  j}{m}\right).
$$
Then the coefficients $a^{2k+1}$ of the Taylor series expansion of $S(a,N)$ is
$$
\frac{2(-1)^k}{N+1}\frac{2^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\left(g(2k+1,N+1)-g(2k+3,N+1)\right).
$$
It is known that (see e.g. this article )
$$
g(k,m)=\frac{m}{2^k}\sum_{r=-\lfloor k/m\rfloor,\,rm+k\,\mathrm{even}}^{\lfloor k/m\rfloor}\binom{k}{\tfrac{rm+k}{2}}.
$$
In particular
$$
g(2k+1,2n+1)=0,\qquad k=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1.\quad (n=N/2)
$$
Observe that this is also a consequence of Chebyshev-Gauss quadrature.
Now, summation with the above formula shows that coefficient of $a^{2k+1}$ in the Taylor series expansion of $S(a,N)$ with $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n-2$ vanish. The first non-vanishing term corresponds to $k=n-1$:
\begin{align}
S(a,N)&\approx (-1)^{N/2}\frac{2(2 a)^{N-1}}{N!}g(N+1,N+1)\\
&=(-1)^{N/2}\frac{2(2 a)^{N-1}}{N!}\frac{2(N+1)}{2^{N+1}}\\
&\approx \frac{(-1)^{N/2} a^{N-1}}{(N-1)!}.
\end{align}
This approximate formula has been confirmed numerically: With increasing $N$, the ratio of the sum and the approximate expression seems to approach $1$.
The higher order coefficients probably can be estimated too with the formulas above, and they will be much smaller than the leading coefficient. This is left as an exercise.
